# A connection is made between server and client but unable to send data via OutputStream in J2ME

Tags: c++, sockets, java-me, indy

I started to program client/server applications in J2ME recently.Now I'm working with c++ builder 2010 indy components (e.g. TidTTCPServer) and J2ME. My application is designed to restart the kerio winroute firewall service from a remote machine. 
My server application is written in c++ builder 2010, I've put a TidTCTServer component into a form which binded to 127.0.0.1:4500. That's listening on port 4500 in local machine.
Then i've added a listbox that i need to add every upcoming packets converted to UnicodeString.

```
//void __fastcall TForm1::servExecute(TIdContext *AContext)

        UnicodeString s;
 UnicodeString txt;
 txt=Trim(AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadLn());
 otvet->Items->Add(txt);
 otvet->ItemIndex=otvet->Items->Count-1;
 if (txt=="1") {
   AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn("Suhrob");
   AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
 }
 if (txt=="2") {
   AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn("Shodi");
   AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
 }
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// void __fastcall TForm1::servConnect(TIdContext *AContext)

  ++counter;
 status->Panels->Items[0]->Text="Connections:" + IntToStr(counter);
 status->Panels->Items[1]->Text="Connected to " + AContext->Connection->Socket->Binding->PeerIP + ":" + AContext->Connection->Socket->Binding->PeerPort;
```

and my client side code looks smth like this:

```
else if (command == send) {                                          
     // write pre-action user code here
            InputStream is=null;
            OutputStream os=null;
            SocketConnection client=null;
            ServerSocketConnection server=null;
            try {
                server = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://"+IP.getString()+":"+PORT.getString());
                // wait for a connection
                client = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://"+IP.getString()+":"+PORT.getString());
                // set application-specific options on the socket. Call setSocketOption to set other options
                client.setSocketOption(SocketConnection.DELAY, 0);
                client.setSocketOption(SocketConnection.KEEPALIVE, 0);
                is = client.openInputStream();
                os = client.openOutputStream();
                // send something to server
                os.write("texttosend".getBytes());
                // read server response
                int c = 0;
                while((c = is.read()) != -1) {
                   // do something with the response
                    System.out.println((char)c);
                }

                // close streams and connection
            }
             catch( ConnectionNotFoundException error )
           {
                 Alert alert = new Alert(
                    "Error", "Not responding!", null, null);
                 alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
                 alert.setType(AlertType.ERROR);
                 switchDisplayable(alert, list);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                 Alert alert = new Alert("ERror", e.toString(), null, null);
                 alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
                 alert.setType(AlertType.ERROR);
                 switchDisplayable(alert, list);
                 e.printStackTrace();

            }

          finally {
          if (is != null) {
            try {
              is.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("Failed to close is!");
            }
            try {
              os.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("Failed to close os!");
            }
          }
          if (server != null) {
            try {
              server.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("Failed to close server!");
            }
          }
          if (client != null) {
            try {
              client.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("Failed to close client!");
            }
          }
        }
```

my client application gets connected with the server but when i try to send data such as

```
os.write("texttosend".getBytes());
```

I cannot get text data on the server using. That's I am not getting sent packets in the server from client.

```
txt=Trim(AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadLn());
```

Guys, where am I wrong? is the way i'm doing is ok?

Or do I need to use StreamConnection instead of SocketConnection?

And when i use telnet to send data it works cool, strings will be added to listbox

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 4500

texttosend
23
asf
```

Any help is appreciated !!!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using `ReadLn()` on the server end.  `ReadLn()` does not exit until a data terminator is encountered (a `LF` line break character is the default terminator) or if a reading timeout occurs (Indy uses infinite timeouts by default).  Your J2ME code is not sending any data terminator, so there is nothing to tell `ReadLn()` when to stop reading.  The reason it works with Telnet is because it does send line break characters.

The other problem with your code is that `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, but your code is updating the UI components in a thread-unsafe manner.  You MUST synchronize with the main thread, such as by using Indy's `TIdSync` and/or `TIdNotify` classes, in order to update your UI safely from inside of the server's event handlers.

Comment: Indy documentation: http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.EN.aspx   A little outdated, but still mostly relavant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, flush method is necessary to call after sending bytes, but ..... finally....
then i tried to include my connection code in a new thread that implements Runnable worked perfectly. Now I've found where I was wrong!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

That's guys you need to include above code in the following block.

```
Thread t= new Thread(this);
t.start();
public void run()
{
//here paste the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [OutputStream.flush()](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)?

If not, try writing to a known working server, instead of one you've created yourself (something like [writing "HELO" to an SMTP server](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node175.html)), this will help you figure out which end the error is at.

Comment: Yes man, then i tried to include my connection code in a new thread that implements Runnable worked perfectly.